# Integrating vaadin elements in angular2-seed project (Error console)

Tags: angular, polymer, vaadin

Hello i have been facing an issue in integrating vaadin elements in angular2 seed project.

I had that first error:

```
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@vaadin/package.json(…)
```

I resolved this by adding code in the file project.config.ts :

```
this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.paths['@vaadin/angular2-polymer'] =
  `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/@vaadin/angular2-polymer`;

this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.packageConfigPaths =
   this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.packageConfigPaths.concat([
  `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/@vaadin/*/package.json`
]);

this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['@vaadin/angular2-polymer'] = {
    main: 'index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

But now I have this error in my console :

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
      at __extends (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@vaadin/angular2-polymer/src/polymer-element.js:5:68)
      at eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@vaadin/angular2-polymer/src/polymer-element.js:12:5)
      at Object.eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@vaadin/angular2-polymer/src/polymer-element.js:23:2)
      at eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@vaadin/angular2-polymer/src/polymer-element.js:280:4)
      at eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@vaadin/angular2-polymer/src/polymer-element.js:281:3)
      at eval (<anonymous>)
Evaluating http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@vaadin/angular2-polymer/src/polymer-element.js
Evaluating http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@vaadin/angular2-polymer/index.js
Evaluating http://localhost:5555/app/app.component.js
Evaluating http://localhost:5555/app/main.js
Error loading http://localhost:5555/app/main.js "Report this error at   https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues"
```

When I remove the line of code `import { PolymerElement } from '@vaadin/angular2-polymer';` of app.component.ts, Angular2 starts successfully.

Is there anyone who has an idea to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your version of Angular 2 is compatible with the angular2-polymer library. If yes, follow the guide in the Vaadin's docs https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/angular2-polymer/overview.html